# FlatList does not output data - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to use a `FlatList` using React-Native and i'm doing it according to the following article.

https://medium.com/react-native-development/how-to-use-the-flatlist-component-react-native-basics-92c482816fe6

I have created a temporary array to test this. But i cannot get my view to show up. What am i doing wrong here?

I'm not even getting the console.log i have given inside the `FlatList`

```
class FlatListTest extends Component {

    constructor() {

        super();

        this.state = {


            data: [

                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'Gal Gadot',
                    img_url: 'http://i0.lisimg.com/9150500/280full.jpg'


                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'Camila Cabello',
                    img_url: 'http://i0.lisimg.com/9150500/280full.jpg'


                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    name: 'Akon',
                    img_url: 'http://i0.lisimg.com/9150500/280full.jpg'


                }

            ]

        }

    }

    render() {

        return (

            <View>

                    <FlatList
                        numColumns={3}
                        style={{flexDirection: 'column'}}>
                        data={this.state.data}
                        renderItem={({item}) => {

                        const content = item;
                        console.log("XXXX ", content);
                        return (
                            <View style={styles.userCard}>

                                <Text>{content.name}</Text>

                            </View>
                        )

                    }}


                    </FlatList>

                </View>

        );
    }
}
```

Comment: any error in console

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN no errors in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

using it like this solved my question

```
<FlatList
     numColumns={3}
     data={this.state.data}
     renderItem={({item}) => <View style={styles.userCard}><Text>{item.name}</Text></View>}
/>
```